# How to ignore rsync warning about vanished files?

Tags: linux, rsync

I get a lot of mails from cronjobs with rsync. And I've tried to ignore it with wrapper script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/rsync "$@"
e=$?
if test $e = 24; then
    exit 0
fi
exit $e
```

And saved it like a /usr/bin/rsync-no24

After that, I changed my script for cronjob:

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE_BASE="/var/www/"
TARGETS="server30"
TARGET_DIR="/var/www/"
RSYNC_BIN="/usr/bin/rsync-no24"
RSYNC_OPTIONS="-aqqq"

/usr/bin/find ${SOURCE_BASE}/typo3temp ! -user www-data -exec chown -R www-data:www-data {} \;

#for SOURCE_DIR in fileadmin uploads typo3temp
#do
        for TARGET_HOST in ${TARGETS}
        do
                ${RSYNC_BIN} ${RSYNC_OPTIONS} ${SOURCE_BASE}/${SOURCE_DIR} ${TARGET_HOST}:${TARGET_DIR}/
        done
#done
```

But anyway I still get mails from cron such as

> file has vanished:
>   "/var/www/stage2/typo3temp/tx_ncstaticfilecache/OnlineBackup/index33.html.5"

How to ignore messages like this? Probably something wrong with wrapper script?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try redirecting `stderr` to `/dev/null`.

Comment: But in this case all errors will be redirected to /dev/null

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `/usr/bin/rsync-no24` with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
(rsync "$@"; if [ $? == 24 ]; then exit 0; else exit $?; fi) 2>&1 | grep -v 'vanished'
```

[source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261863/60244)

(on a side note, I don't think there's a difference between `RSYNC_OPTIONS="-aqqq"` and `RSYNC_OPTIONS="-aq"`